# InitialContext() keeps spawning new threads when OpenJMS is hung

Tags: java, jms, memory-leaks, freeze

All,
      In my test scenario, I have openJMS in a suspended state (deliberately). The problem is that the application accessing it keeps spawning new threads which remain in a "blocked" state even though I am using Future/Callable with a timeout. I can see that a timeout happens, but that thread still remains in a blocked state.

The culprit is this single line: `initContext = new InitialContext(env);`

I have that wrapped in a try/catch/finally and in finally I check if initContext != null and the close it. Problem is that its not null because its hung and times out. Eventually I can see many threads being spawned and in blocked state.

Any idea on how to tackle this? Thanks in advance!